# producto de vectores

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

            int [] vectorA = new int [5];
            int [] vectorB = new int [5];
            int r, producto;

            for (r = 0; r < vectorA.length; r++){
                System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad del vector A: ");
                vectorA[r] = teclado.nextInt(); 
            }
            for (r = 0; r < vectorB.length; r++){


            System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad del vector B: ");
                    vectorB[r] = teclado.nextInt(); 
                }
                System.out.print("El producto es: ");
                producto = 0;
                for (r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                    System.out.print(vectorA[r] + " , " + vectorB[r]);
                    producto = (producto + (vectorA[r] * vectorB[r]));
                }
                System.out.print(producto);
            }

        }
```

Necesito leer un vector de 5 números en un arreglo A, lo mismo para un arreglo B, que calcule e imprima el producto de A*B para lo cual se multiplica A1* B1... A5*B5, obteniendo al final la sumatoria de los productos
Si me puedan ayudar por favor no se en que estoy fallando

Comment: No estarias fallando en nada. cual es el error que recibis?

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es mostrar simplemente un resultado, entonces estas imprimiendo consecutivamente un valor, pero si lo que quieres es que el algoritmo resulva todo y te lance de una vez el resultado simplemente tienes que saber que debes imprimir y donde. Tambien debes recordar que si vas a hacer un incremento en una variable debe estar inicializada o debe valer algo por ejemplo, algo asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        int [] vectorA = new int [5];
        int [] vectorB = new int [5];
        int r; 
        // INICIALIZAS PRODUCTO A 0 PARA QUE PUEDA SER ACOMULATIVO
        int producto = 0;

        for (r = 0; r < vectorA.length; r++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad del vector A: ");
            vectorA[r] = teclado.nextInt(); 
        }
        for (r = 0; r < vectorB.length; r++){


        System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad del vector B: ");
                vectorB[r] = teclado.nextInt(); 
            }
            System.out.print("El producto es: ");
            producto = 0;
            for (r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                System.out.print(vectorA[r] + " , " + vectorB[r]);
                //Signos de incremento a una variable
                producto += vectorA[r] * vectorB[r];
            }
            //System.out.print(producto);  -> Aqui tenias tu impresion
        }

        System.out.println(producto); // Puedes colocarla aqui afuera para que te      
                                      // muestre un resultado final

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando estás recorriendo el for en esta parte del código:

```
for (r = 0; r < 5; r++){
   System.out.print(vectorA[r] + " , " + vectorB[r]);
   producto = (producto + (vectorA[r] * vectorB[r]));
}
```

El System.out.print, estás mostrando solo los valores y no multiplicando como lo deseas, debería estar así:

```
for (r = 0; r < 5; r++){                
    System.out.print((vectorA[r] * vectorB[r]) + " , ");
    producto = (producto + (vectorA[r] * vectorB[r]));
}
```

Ese es el único "error" por lo que veo.
Saludos